# UrlFetchApp.fetch() throwing "Exception: Address not available" (Previously Working)

Tags: google-apps-script, http-get, urlfetch

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` just started throwing `Exception: Address not available` while trying to retrieve information from an API that we run on a home server behind a residential connection. The API is publicly facing and we have successfully tested accessing it from different networks.

This only started recently, could it be that Google started blacklisting certain IPs/TLDs or something like that? (The site also uses the free TLD `.cf`)

The same code is working with other APIs.

Here is the code --

```
var getOptions = {
      "method"  : 'GET',
      "followRedirects" : true,
      "muteHttpExceptions": true
    };
var q = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://myurl.cf:3000/ajskdfnsoenfkasn', getOptions);
```

Comment: Could you provide the URL you are trying to access?

Comment: Prefer not to share it as POST and GET requests are open to the public.

Comment: How do you know that the API is working properly?

Comment: Hi Ruben, thanks for your reply. I know because I can execute a GET request from connections outside my home wifi and it returns a response.